# If I edit an EDMX file, does it make changes to any files besides itself and it's designer file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model, edmx

I made a change and undid it to my edmx file, but it hasn't worked the same since.  Wondering if another file was changed behind the scenes that needs refreshing?

Comment: Totally vague. Impossible to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .edmx file contains the model mapping metadata that is copied into your assembly as Resources at build time, and several other project files are generated at design-time based on the .edmx file.  The DbContext type and all of the Entity type definitions are generated as source code files from the .edmx file, and Visual Studio re-generates them after any changes to the .edmx.

If you alter the .edmx file outside of visual studio, or perhaps revert just the .edmx file from your source repo, your other generated files may be out-of-sync.

The design-time generation is driven by Visual Studio's [Custom Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/custom-tools?view=vs-2017) functionality.  So you should be able to right-click on the .edmx and select "run custom tool" from the context menu, and then do the same for any .tt files nested under the .edmx in the Solution Explorer to regenerate all the source code files.

And, as a last resort, if you don't have a lot of customization in the .edmx you can simply delete it and regenerate it from the database.

Comment: This seems like it could be the culprit to my issues.  Is there a way to resync the mappings?

Comment: In the end, I had to delete the edmx and recreate it from scratch.  These things are sensitive!